# How to change UIStatusBarStyle from .lightContent to .default after scrolling starts in a table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, ios11, uistatusbar

I am trying to change the preferredStatusBarStyle of a table view controller from .lightContent to .default when scrolling starts?
Here is the initial state : 
[image]

And this is the final state : 
[image]
I am relatively new to iOS development. Please provide details on how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out the solution after scouting for a while....

If you want to change the status bar style any time after the view has appeared you can use this:

In file info.list add row: **View controller-based status bar appearance** and set it to **YES**

```
var viewIsDark = Bool()

func makeViewDark() {

viewIsDark = true
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

func makeViewLight() {

viewIsDark = false
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {

if viewIsDark {
    return .lightContent 
} else {
    return .default 
} 
}
```

The above code works if your view controller isn't embedded in a Navigation Controller. If it is embedded in a Navigation Controller, add this to the bottom of the view controller :

```
 extension UINavigationController
{
    override open var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
 // code goes here
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a way to store a variable that is of type `UIStatusBarStyle` somewhere in your view controller.

Then in your view controller you add:

```
var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return statusBarStyleVariable // This is the variable you created
}
```

When you want to switch the styles, just change the value of your `statusBarStyleVariable` and do `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`

EDIT:
This can be your variable code:

```
var statusBarStyleVariable: UIStatusBarStyle {
    didSet {
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}
```

This way, whenever you change the value of the your variable, it'll refresh automatically.